# Part of Code in Windows Batch File Not Executing

Tags: windows, batch-file

So, I don't have much experience with batch scripting and use regular programming languages quite a lot. I'm trying to write something very simple and don't understand why half of my code is not executing as I expect. Perhaps I'm breaking some cardinal rule in Windows Batch scripting. Right now the code below just makes the new directory, and then the script appears to stop and not complete any of the code involving the time, copying, or clearing of a file. Anyone see what's wrong with this code?

```
   @echo off

rem check for directory
if not exist fileDir (
 mkdir fileDir

)

rem check for file...
if file.txt exists (

  REM get computer name
  set hostName = echo %computername%

  rem get time format
  SET HOUR=%time:~0,2%
  SET dtStamp9=%date:~-4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_0%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2% 
  SET dtStamp24=%date:~-4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

  if "%HOUR:~0,1%" == " " (SET dtStamp=%dtStamp9%) else (SET dtStamp=%dtStamp24%)

  type file.txt >> ./fileDir/%hostName%_%dtStamp%.LOG

  REM clearing file contents of file.txt.
  break > file.txt
  )
```

Comment: I'm no batch expert but at the top u wrote `if not exist fileDir`. Later u wrote `if file.txt exists` it seems like your syntax is inconsistent. Try '`if exist file.txt`'

Comment: @KenWhite: precisely. `break` command show nothing, so the redirection creates an empty file, that is, "clear file contents of file.txt".

Comment: @Aacini: Ah, nice. :-) I checked to see if break did anything, but didn't actually check the output. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
if file.txt exists (
```

is not a valid batch file command.  There is not `exists` option for `if` the option is `exist` singular and it must go before the file name.  So the line should be:

```
if exist file.txt (
```

You can get more information on using `if` in a batch file by typing `help if` in a command prompt window.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something obvious such as this. I certainly appreciate it!